# Binary Classification of Labels with Similar Feature Distributions

Tags: classification, similarities, feature-engineering

I wish to classify gene interactions as 'Validated' and 'Unvalidated' based on certain features of each interaction. Each interaction has 10 different features.

However, the feature distributions of each interaction are highly similar. For example:

[image: Histogram of feature 'Gene Length Difference' for 'Validated' and 'Unvalidated']

[image: Histogram of feature 'Coverage' for 'Validated' and 'Unvalidated']

I have two questions:

1. My hunch/hope is that though the feature distributions are similar, the individual validated interaction may have a very different set of features compared with an unvalidated interaction.

   Is there a statistical method to measure such a combination of features?

   Alternatively, is there a preprocessing method to calculate features on top of these the 10 features, which may better segregate the validated and unvalidated interactions?
2. I have tried several supervised learning classifiers of these 'Validated' gene interactions: linear regression, logistic regression, Support Vector Machines, and Random Forest.

   However, these classifiers all have poor precision of the 'Validated': ~57-60% when  57% of the interactions themselves are validated. Hence, they perform worse than a Dummy classifier which simply labels all interactions as 'Validated'.
   I have tried these classifiers choosing different subsets of features, of different sizes, as well as with different training and test set sizes, all with limited success at improving the precision.

   Is there a algorithm that may be suitable for increasing the precision for classification of these interactions?

Comment: Given a relatively low number of features (10 is doable), you might learn some useful correlations/differences via [parallel coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_coordinates).

Comment: Thank you! A look at the parallel coordinates plot shows that many of the features are indeed correlated-- and that there isn't a clear distinction between the Validated and Unvalidated genes across most of the features. It was just a bad question, I suppose.